# How can I store a vector of integers to disk and read the integers from the saved file in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, file-writing

I have integers in a vector that I want to store in a file. I'm not sure I am saving it and would like to be able to read the integers from the file.

My attempt. It prints out the integer 88, the second one I stored.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>


class ValueGet {
public:
   int data;
   ValueGet() {
   data = 0;
   }
};

int main() {


    int first_int = 47;
    int second_int = 88;
    std::vector<int> int_vec;
    int_vec.push_back(first_int);
    int_vec.push_back(second_int);

    std::ofstream outfile("int_outfile.txt", std::ofstream::binary);
    outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(int_vec.data() /* or &v[0] pre-C++11 */), sizeof(int) * int_vec.size());
    outfile.close();

    ValueGet vg;
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("int_outfile.txt", std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::out); // Opens a file in binary mode for input operations i.e., getting data from file.
    if (!file)
        std::cout << "File Not Found.";
    else {
        file.seekg(0); // To make sure that the data is read from the starting position of the file.
        // while (file.read((char *)&vg, sizeof(vg))) // Iterates through the file till the pointer reads the last line of the file.
            while (file.read((char*)&vg, sizeof(vg)));

            std::cout << "Did it load? " << vg.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, `int_vec` is a `std::vector<int>` object. It won't *decay* to a pointer like an array, hence your cast is really invalid. Secondly, the vector object is basically just a holder of a pointer to the actual data, so writing the object will just save the pointer, not the data that the pointer might point to. The comment you have in the cast actually show one simple way to solve your problem.

Comment: The reading also seems to be odd, since you have an (unknown) amount of `int` values. What is `vg`? What is `ValueGet`? Why do you attempt to read into the `vg` object? And why do you open the input file in *output* mode?

Comment: Lastly a note about binary files: Please don't use them. Unless required, use *text* files to write the values and data as text. Then read as text as well.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am learning a lot about C++. I have made most of the updates to address.

Comment: Please don't "fix" the code in the question. That makes it (and possible answers) totally worthless as it no longer have the problem you ask about. Remember that questions and answers here are not only to help you right now, but also for future visitors that might have the same or a similar problem.

Comment: Right. Sorry. I just didn't see a record online of where to write integers to a file and read them. To and from vectors. I've opened the txt file after writing what I thought would be two integers and it looks like there is just one integer in there.

Comment: So, the program writes a **binary** file with a **".txt"** extension?

Comment: I take it that is not ideal? Maybe I should delete this question.

Comment: Note, also, an often overlooked point: the only portable way to read a binary file is from the application that wrote it. That's why pretty much everything is done with text files.

Answer (score 0):

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(int_vec /* or &v[0] pre-C++11 */), sizeof(int) * vec_of_vec_of_tensor.size());
```

should be

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(int_vec.data() /* or &v[0] pre-C++11 */), sizeof(int) * int_vec.size());
```

Since `ValueGet` is undefined in the code above I've no idea how to advise on reading the data back. But if you want to read back to a vector, then you must make sure the vector is the correct size and use the `data` method again to read directly into the vector's data.

`seekg` is unnecessary in the code above.